# Is a server able to record both the MAC address and the IP address of a computer which accesses it?

Tags: webserver

Is a server able to record both the MAC address and the IP address of a computer which accesses it?

For example, when the server offers webpages or something to download.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve.  The MAC address isn't going to be broadcasted outside of your intranet.  So if this server is outside of your network it won't log it, unless the client itself sends it, but thats an entirely different story.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, when the server offers webpages or something to download.

If this is a web server sitting within a LAN and on the same subnet as the users, then yes, MAC addresses can be logged from machines on the same LAN and same subnet.

But if this is a web server sitting at some hosting service in the middle of who knows where, then know. MAC addresses are not transmitted as a part of a general IP protocol connection. Meaning that if a MAC address is transmitted, it would only be of the last router the packet went through before getting to the web server and not the client machine that was most likely dozens of network hops away.

Comment: For example, when ssh to a sever. When browsing Google Books.